# Handle exceptions during WCF service instance creation

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-container

I am using Unity.Wcf to inject dependencies in the service class and it work fine. But if I configure my dependencies incorrectly an exception is thrown by unity that it cannot build up my service instance which is correct. Does anyone knows where I can handle this exception to log it for example? It's much easier to check the log than debug it every time.

Comment: can you provide the code you are using?  Generally an exception being thrown from a constructor is a security issue.

Comment: When a request is done then the ServiceHost is created behind the scenes (in wcf.unity when it's used). And an exception happens because unity cannot construct the instance because I forgot to register one of the dependencies. I just want to log the exception... So there is no particular code that is throwing the exception that I can provide.

Comment: Are you self hosting and calling UnityServiceHost.Open() in your code? That's what you need to wrap a try/catch around.

Comment: I am not, it is in the IIS and I am using Unity.Wcf for interception.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to capture the exception is to override the CreateServiceHost methods in the service factory.  Call base.CreateServiceHost() inside of a try...catch block and use your logging component of choice to save the exception to the log.  Other than logging the error, the behavior will be the same.

```
public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
{
    try {
        return base.CreateServiceHost(constructorString, baseAddresses);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // log here
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a correct solution. I have tried this but what happened is that the host is created, but the instance of your service is really created afterwards and outside of this call. So catching exception here does not catch the service creation exceptions.

Comment: I'm using the config file with Unity to allow the authentication provider to be changed. The case I tested with the above code was to change the config value for the "mapTo" attribute to a non-existent class. In the log I get an InvalidOperationException: "The type name or alias System.Services.Security.Authenticators.MissingDependency, System.Services.Security could not be resolved."

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations I have found out how the instance is created and it seems there is no way to add logging to it easily. The only way it to either change the source code of Unity.Wcf or to inherit few classes and override default behavior. For those who are interested the logic is following: UnityServiceHostFactory creates UnityServiceHost, UnityServiceHost adds behavior class UnityInstanceProvider, this UnityInstanceProvider has a GetInstance method that creates the service and does Unity resolving. So to log something you need to do one of the following:

1. Substitute this class with yours and inherit both UnityServiceHostFactory and UnityServiceHost
2. Get the sources and change something right in this class (UnityInstanceProvider).